# Como fazer um redirecionamento via .htaccess de um subdomínio para o domínio principal?

Tags: htaccess

Tenho um domínio (www.dominio.com.br) e uma subpasta (www.dominio.com.br/pasta) e gostaria de redirecionar todos os links dessa pasta para o domínio.

Exemplos:
www.dominio.com.br/pasta
www.dominio.com.br/pasta/noticia/nome-da-noticia
www.dominio.com.br/pasta/contato.php
www.dominio.com.br/pasta/tag/nome-da-tag
www.dominio.com.br/pasta/trabalhos.php

Todos os links requisitados da "pasta" com e sem extensão, quero redirecioná-los para o domínio principal.

Como faço? E aonde coloco o arquivo .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie um diretório chamado "pasta" no *DocumentRoot* onde estão os arquivos páginas do **www.dominio.com.br** ("/var/www/html", "/opt/site/" etc) e dentro dele crie o arquivo ".htaccess" com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.dominio.com.br/$1

</IfModule>
```

Neste caso **TUDO**, o `^(.*)$` no REGEX, que chega em http://www.dominio.com.br/pasta/ será redirecionado para http://www.dominio.com.br/; o $1 no final é justamente o resto da URL ("index.html", "admin.php", "post/2018/03/26" etc).

Comment: Dessa forma fiz um teste assim:

www.dominio.com.br/pasta/subpasta

redirecionou o endereço para:

www.dominio.com.br/subpasta

Comment: Então funcionou?

Comment: Não! Era pra ter ido pra home do site.

Comment: Remova o "$1" do final, é ele que complementa a URL. Tinha entendido que você queria também traduzir os acessos.

Comment: Deu certo! Muito obrigada.